# SSD Boot drive and encrypted HD

Tags: ssd, filevault

Have an SSD installed in my MBP's optical bay. All works well other than being unable to directly log on to my main home folder, which I think is due to the fact they this folder (still on the HDD) is filevault 2 encrypted (workaround is log into a second "test account", log out and the I can successfully log into my main user account).

I really don't need to have filevault turned on, but cannot find a way to turn it off now that I boot off the SSD.  Is it possible?  Advisable?

Anticipatory thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

If you have an external drive where everything is backed-up, the easiest thing would be to erase the HDD choosing `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` then restore from the backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't remove OS X from your HDD just boot on it and go to the system preferences and disable Filevault.

You can set which driver to boot in the System Preferences.