# How can I make a secondary encrypted volume open during the boot process?

Tags: ssd, filevault, encryption, login-screen

When booting off a FileVault encrypted volume, OSX is capable of accessing the volume for the boot process once the user has entered their password at FileVault prompt. I want to configure my system so it also can access a secondary drive (containing my homedir) during this process.

- After an SSD upgrade, I have an SSD as boot drive and HDD as data drive.
- A secondary account exists on the SSD, with username "admin".
- My preferred account, username "chris", has the home directory on the HDD, with symlink `/Users/chris` -> `/Volumes/Tracto/Users/chris`.
- User "chris" has homedir set to `/Users/chris` (situation is the same when homedir set to `/Volumes/Tracto/Users/chris`, no change in behaviour).
- If I log in as "chris" from the FileVault login screen, the machine boots and then shows the message "**You are unable to log in to the user account "chris" at this time.** Logging in to the account failed because an error occurred".
- If I log in as "admin" from FileVault login, the system boots and logs in, at which point I can switch to the preferred account and operate as normal.
- The preferred and secondary accounts have the same password, which is the one found in the secondary account's KeyChain associated with decrypting the drive.

To eliminate the double-login requirement, I hope to configure the system so that FileVault login decrypts both the SSD and HDD, boots off SSD and logs me into the preferred (HDD-homedir) account.

OSX is 10.11.4, machine is mid-2010 iMac, SSD and HDD are internal.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27033/ssd-boot-drive-and-encrypted-hd?rq=1 - Similar question which didn't come up in initial search, but David didn't want to retain FileVault on both drives, which I do.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work when your home directory is on a non-boot volume which is encrypted. If your home dir was on the boot drive or another unencrypted disk then you can have encrypted disks mount at login by adding the password to your keychain. But that's about it I believe.